# How to convert the hex value that I receive from SNMP?

Tags: python, hex, snmp, pysnmp

I use [PYSNMP](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/changelog.html) as my tool for working with SNMP.
Many of the OIDs in snmp are represented by hex values.
Here is an example of the serial number OID:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.1602.1.2.1.4.0 = Hex-String: 0115434e443846374d485646
```

I could transform this hex value into a more understandable type, by converting it to an [integer](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) or to a [string](http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx).
The problem is that I have no way of knowing the intended type of the hex value, whether string or integer.
So for example the Hex-string `0115434e443846374d485646`, when converted to a [string](http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx) equals `CND8F7MHVF`, but when converted to an [integer](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) equals `335190294349398493576582726`.
In this example the hex value should be converted into an string if I would want to retrieve the proper result, but in other cases I might of needed to convert the hex value into a integer to get the proper result, because Serial Numbers can also be integers.
How should I convert the Hex-String to receive the intended value of the Hex-String?

Comment: Find the original MIB documents that contain the definitions. Then why a type is defined in that way would be never clearer. If you just check the returned values, of course you would be puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

In SNMP, HEX values are more commonly associated with OCTET STRING type than with INTEGERs.

When SNMP puts an INTEGER into a packet, it is clearly tagged as such. On receiving end you always know that it is INTEGER so you may convert it into whatever base you wish and that won't change its semantics or value.

OCTET STRING type accommodates a sequence of bytes. That may represent a printable string or a MAC address or potentially something application-specific. Regardless of the contents, value in the wire is tagged the same (e.g. at the packet level). Therefore the only way to figure out how to interpret particular OCTET STRING value is to look at the OID associated with that value (via OBJECT-TYPE definition in MIB).

To help interpret base SNMP types (and OCTET STRING in particular) SNMP has a dummy type called TEXTUAL-CONVENTION. It defines a layout of octets in OCTET STRING to produce something human-friendly from it automatically.

In case of pysnmp, all you need is to load MIB where managed object in question is defined and let pysnmp do the rest by applying .prettyPrint() to the objects it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're doing it wrong as you are converting MAC ADDRESS(which is HEX-BASED by definition) to STRING.

Usually, the exact kind of type in SNMP is defined in MIB-s, this types are based on a limited subset of SMIv1/SMIv2 types and there should not be any misunderstandings.

Comment: mac address was just an example, sometimes it's a Serial Number or an IP address or almost anything. And if there is some type that im missing then can you please give me some code that retrieves the correct SMIv1/SMIv2 types.

Comment: I edited my question to refer to a serial number and not a mac address to avoid confusion.